# Why does the capra demon take additional damage from black night weapons?

Tags: dark-souls

Is there something in the story or the lore that explains why black knight weapons do extra damage to the capra demon? I know occult weapons are bossing weapons. However the black knight weapons don't seem to have an occult aux number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing to explain exactly *why* this happens, only that it does.

> *Like all Black Knight weapons, it [Black Knight Sword] deals additional damage to demon enemies like the Taurus Demon and Capra Demon*

Any attempt to explain this is merely speculation, but a suggestion might be that the Black Knight Weapons are similar to the Silver Knight Weapons, which have a Faith Stat requirement, and while the Black Knight weapons don't share this requirement, it's a possibility they still share a similar effect vs. demons.